# Doctrine: Set field value to SQL expression

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I need to set value in mapped record to some arbitrary sql expression, so on `obj.save()` it would be used directly, w/out escaping/quoting.

Something like this:

```
obj.location = "Point($x, $y)";
obj.save();
```

Which should result in query like `UPDATE ... SET location = Point(..., ...) WHERE ...;`

However I cannot find anything like this in the docs, except DQL `->update()->set()`. I'd prefer to not use DQL, since it is used in both insert and update contexts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out its just

`obj.location = new Doctrine_Expression("Point(10, 10)");`

but not documented anywhere besides source code.